# How do I handle entities that have multiple data per entity in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a SVM based classifier that classifies a chunk of data into some categories. Now, I want to classify some entities which each has multiple chunks of these data, into the same categories maybe using majority voting or something like that and then produce reports like precision/recall/confusion matrix etc.

Does scikit-learn offer ways to easily do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All scikit-learn models expect a flat features vector for each sample. So to deal with more structured input (or output) you will have to come up with your own wrapper. Based on your succinct description of your task it seems that a majority voting scheme might be a reasonable approach.

Comment: Actually, this is not true. The SVMs can take Gram matrices, which means that (for smallish problems) arbitrary kernels can be used (tree kernels, graph kernels, etc.)

Comment: Indeed I forgot about precomputed kernels.